# image post feed with django does not display images

Tags: html, django, image, feed, social-media

Currently working on a very simple social media and since yesterday the images in the post feed either disappear or i get a value error:

ValueError at /
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.16
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Render_2\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py, line 40, in _require_file
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Render_2\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:
['C:\Users\Render_2\PycharmProjects\djangoProject',
'C:\Users\Render_2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.zip',
'C:\Users\Render_2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs',
'C:\Users\Render_2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib',
'C:\Users\Render_2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32',
'C:\Users\Render_2\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv',
'C:\Users\Render_2\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\venv\lib\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 05 Jan 2023 12:14:48 +0000

I have honestly no idea why it is messed up now, since it was running just fine yesterday morning.
Please help me out to understand this issue.
Here is the rest of the code.

the index.html:
for the post and for the display in the feed

```
<form action="upload" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <p class="my-3 leading-6"> Upload pics <br>
                                    </p>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="file" name="image_upload">
                                        <!--<a href="#" class="button soft-warning small"> Choose file</a>-->
                                        <textarea class="button soft-warning small" name="caption" placeholder="caption..."></textarea>
                                        <br>
                                        <button class="button bg-blue-700" type="submit">upload</button>
                                    </div>
                                    </form>


{% for post in posts reversed %}

                        <div class="bg-white shadow rounded-md  -mx-2 lg:mx-0">

    
                            <!-- post header-->
                            <div class="flex justify-between items-center px-4 py-3">
                                <div class="flex flex-1 items-center space-x-4">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <div class="bg-gradient-to-tr from-yellow-600 to-pink-600 p-0.5 rounded-full">  
                                            <img src="{% static 'assets/images/avatars/user.png' %}" class="bg-gray-200 border border-white rounded-full w-8 h-8">
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                    <span class="block capitalize font-semibold "><a href="/profile/{{ post.user }}">@{{ post.user }}  </a></span>
                                </div>
                              <div>
                                <a href="#"> <i class="icon-feather-more-horizontal text-2xl hover:bg-gray-200 rounded-full p-2 transition -mr-1 "></i> </a>
                                <div class="bg-white w-56 shadow-md mx-auto p-2 mt-12 rounded-md text-gray-500 hidden text-base border border-gray-100  " uk-drop="mode: hover;pos: top-right">
                              
                                    <ul class="space-y-1">
                                      <li> 
                                          <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-md ">
                                           <i class="uil-share-alt mr-1"></i> Share
                                          </a> 
                                      </li>
                                      <li> 
                                          <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-md ">
                                           <i class="uil-edit-alt mr-1"></i>  Edit Post 
                                          </a> 
                                      </li>
                                      <li> 
                                          <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-md ">
                                           <i class="uil-comment-slash mr-1"></i>   Disable comments
                                          </a> 
                                      </li> 
                                      <li> 
                                          <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-md ">
                                           <i class="uil-favorite mr-1"></i>  Add favorites 
                                          </a> 
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                        <hr class="-mx-2 my-2 ">
                                      </li>
                                      <li> 
                                          <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-red-500 hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-red-500 rounded-md ">
                                           <i class="uil-trash-alt mr-1"></i>  Delete
                                          </a> 
                                      </li>
                                    </ul>
                                
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div uk-lightbox>
                                <a href="{{posts.images.url}}">
                                    <img src="{{posts.images.url}}" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            
    
                            <div class="py-3 px-4 space-y-3"> 
                               
                                <div class="flex space-x-4 lg:font-bold">
                                    <a href="/like-post?post_id={{ post.id }}" class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                                        <div class="p-2 rounded-full text-black">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" width="25" height="25" class="">
                                                <path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" />
                                            </svg>
                                            {% if post.number_of_likes == 0 %}
                                            <p>no likes</p>
                                            {% else%}
                                            <p>liked by {{ post.number_of_likes }} users</p>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </div>
                                        
                                    </a>
                                    <!--<a href="#" class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                                        <div class="p-2 rounded-full text-black">
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" width="25" height="25" class="">
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 5v8a2 2 0 01-2 2h-5l-5 4v-4H4a2 2 0 01-2-2V5a2 2 0 012-2h12a2 2 0 012 2zM7 8H5v2h2V8zm2 0h2v2H9V8zm6 0h-2v2h2V8z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>
                                        -->
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="{{ posts.images.url }}" class="flex items-center space-x-2 flex-1 justify-end" download>
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="25" height="25" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><g fill="currentColor"><path d="M8.5 1.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 10 0h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h6c-.314.418-.5.937-.5 1.5v6h-2a.5.5 0 0 0-.354.854l2.5 2.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l2.5-2.5A.5.5 0 0 0 10.5 7.5h-2v-6z"/></g></svg>
                                        
                                    </a>
                                </div>
    </div>
    
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
```

So the main problem seems to be this one . When I change it to the originally working code post.image.url I get the value error. If I leave the code just as it is, no images are displayed.

this is the views.py:

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all() #--> returns the post objects as a list
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': posts})
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user.username
        image = request.FILES.get('media/viewposts_images')
        caption = request.POST['caption']

        new_post = Post.objects.create(caption=caption)
        new_post.save()

        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return redirect('/')
    return HttpResponse('upload view')
```

this is the class in models.py:

```
class Post (models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # user id == post id
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/posts_images")
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    number_of_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

and these are the urls.py of the app

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'), #==homepage
    path('upload', views.upload, name='upload'),
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup')
```

and this is the path of the media folder in this project...
C:\Users\Render_2\PycharmProjects\djangoProject\media\posts_images

I´ve already did a few posts and the images and everything was working, the images also got there easily. however, now it seams the folder is not reachable...? I just changed a few things in the index.html and tried to go back today, but I can´t find the mistake. It´s my first django project, so I am a little bit lost. also if I change the line in views.py def index: return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': posts}) to smth else than posts the website is working again but without the posts... I´m just looking for a simple method of having a post feed.

Thank you for any tips.
Have a great day, bye.

Answer (score 0):

so the error happened due to some posts not having an image, so, before the uklightbox in the index.html displaying the image post, an if statement was missing.

```
                        {% if post.image %}

                        <div uk-lightbox>
                            <a href="{{ post.image.url}}">
                                <img src="{{post.image.url}}" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        {% endif %}
```

now it works. the social media was not working anymore due to me posting only text based posts, without considering that the index.html will look for an image to display. Now both works, text and/or images.